# How to upload file in Google Drive fetched from a 3rd party API using NodeJS and Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am fetching a file from a third-party API and it is returning me a base64 string of data as a response. Now when I'm trying to upload files to Drive using Drive API and that base 64 string it's working but not opening the files in the Drive except text file.

```
const drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth: oauth2Client,
  });
  var fileMetadata = {
    name: fileToUpload.name,
    mimeType: fileToUpload.mimeType,
    parents: [fileToUpload.parentFolderId],
  };
  drive.files.create(
    {
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: {
        body: fileToUpload.data, //the base64 string got from the response.
        mimeType: fileToUpload.mimeType,
      },
      fields: "id",
    },
    function (err, file) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

When opening the file in Drive it's not opening.
[image]

Comment: Whch kind of mimeType do you expect? What happens if you download the file? Can you open it locally?

Comment: It can be any mimeType file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNL4r31etxWdL0oMaPNhgZTyYh7VR_jR/view?usp=sharing this is the base64 string response I'm getting from the API.

Comment: @Mridul Kapil Thank you for replying. I confirmed it. In your situation, my answer cannot be used. Because, from your question, I proposed the script for using the base64 data. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because in this case, my answer cannot be used for the binary data. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: the Content-Type is application/octetstream and Transfer-Encoding is chunked in the first API response.